# Trouble about assign char pointer in C

Tags: c, string, malloc

I have a simple C program about assign char pointer and malloc like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789";
    char* str1 = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(str1, str);
    printf("%s\n\n", str1);

    char* str2 = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    str2 = str1;    
    printf("%s\n", str2);

    return 0;
}
```

And the result is:

```
0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789

0123456789 0123456789 01!
```

So why the str2 just gets 25 characters from str1? And where is the "!" (in the end of str2) come from?

Could you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to understand [arrays and pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) before you can use strings or malloc().

Comment: Thank you. I am a newbie to C. Your link is really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't malloc enough space. `sizeof(char *)` is the amount of memory required to hold a pointer (NOT anything to do with where that pointer is pointing).

Change both mallocs to: `malloc(sizeof str)`, or `malloc(strlen(str) + 1)`.

Also, `str2 = str1` causes a memory leak. It makes the pointer `str2` point to where `str1` points, and then you have that malloc'd block with nothing pointing to it.

In your original code, when you write into memory you don't own, anything could happen; it's not really useful to try and investigate exactly why you get some particular garbage instead of some other particular garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sizeof` is wrong, you're `malloc`-ing 4 or 8 bytes, depending on your pointer size, you should `malloc(sizeof(str)` since that is what you're copying into it.

Also, note that `str2 = str1` simply overwrites the `str2` pointer, so you have a memory leak, as the `malloc` in your `str2` initialization gets lost.